# Inserting captured image into database issue (Cordova/SQlite/JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, cordova

I am attempting to store captured images into my database however I cannot seem to get the actual data of the image.

Once the camera takes a photo it should be automatically stored, however I have the query alert, and it shows as the image being undefined.

I'm sure there are a few problems with my coding, as my coding isn't the best.

alert(_Query3); gives me the following:

```
INSERT INTO Gallery(myImage) values ('undefined')
```

JavaScript:

```
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
          var db;
          function onDeviceReady() {
            db = window.openDatabase("SoccerEarth", "2.0", "SoccerEarthDB", 2 * 1024 * 1024);
            db.transaction(function(tx) {
           tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Gallery (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, myImage BLOB)');
            }, errorE, successS);
          }

function successS() {
  alert("Camera database ready!");
  document.getElementById("btnCamera").onclick = function() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
      quality: 50,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
    });
  };
}

function onSuccess(tx, imageData) {
alert("Camera test 1");
  var image = document.getElementById("lastPhoto");
  image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
  base64imageData = imageData;
  var _Query3 = ("INSERT INTO Gallery(myImage) values ('"+ base64imageData +"')");
  alert(_Query3);
  tx.executeSql(_Query3);
}
            /*   function successCamera() {
               navigator.notification.alert("Image has been stored", null, "Information", "ok");
                 $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#page4" );
             } */

function onFail(message) {
  alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}

function errorE(err) {
  alert("Error processing SQL: " + err.code);
}
```

Comment: where is the declaration for base64imageData? or just pass imageData in the query and check what alert shows.

Comment: I've just tried a few things, imageData is undefined so i assume there is no data there? I even put image.src just to see the result and it came up with 'data:image/jpeg;base64,undefined' so clearly imageData is not pulling any data.

Comment: @Mahdi : Have you found solution for storing image binary data into SQLite  in Cordova-based app?

Answer (score 0):

I might have found a solution to your problem. Your onSuccess Callback seems to be of the wrong syntax. I don't understand how the "tx" variable can be used with the imageData variable because only a single parameter can be used  for the onSuccess as far as I know. If my assumptions are correct, then the Base64 encoding of the image data must be stored in the tx parameter.

Let me know if this has managed to solve your issue.

You can refer to [camera.onSuccess](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/#cameraonsuccess--function) for the proper declaration.